# Prestashop: Display products from childcategories if parent category is empty

Tags: categories, prestashop

Please help me with the following:

My website shows, when chossing a category, the corresponding sub-categories, and the message "there are no products in this category". This happens while drilling-down until one arrives to the lower level sub-category.

I would like to show all the products of its sub-categories instead.

How can I do this please?

Thanks a lot for your advice,

Steven

Answer (score 3):

Open `/controllers/CategoryController.php` and add the below code to the `process()` method, notice the comments telling you where to start and end adding code

```
public function process()
{
    ....
            }
            if ($this->category->id != 1)
                $this->productListAssign();

            /* MODIFICATION STARTS HERE */  
            if(!(isset($this->cat_products) AND $this->cat_products) ){ 
                $this->category->id=array();
                foreach($subCategories as $k=>$v){
                    $this->category->id[]=$v['id_category'];
                }
                $this->productListAssign();

            }
            /* MODIFICATION ENDS HERE */    

            self::$smarty->assign(array( ...
}
```

Then Open Up `classes/Category.php` and change the line for the WHERE CLAUSE of the SQL query inside `public function getProducts` from

```
    WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id.($active ? ' AND p.`active` = 1' : '').'
```

TO

```
    WHERE cp.`id_category` '.(is_array($this->id)?" IN(".implode(',',$this->id).") ": "=".(int)$this->id).($active ? ' AND p.`active` = 1' : '').'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change anything to achieve this.

Simply assign product to not only subcategory it is in, but aswell to parent categories (in product edit in BO).

Comment: Any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can also just install the Layered Navigation Module (blocklayered). The default behaviour of this module is to show the subcategories products, even if the selector-widget is not visible/active on the pages.

Answer (score 1):

In the categoryController.php, you can find the `process()` method. That's the one that get all the informations displayed on the category pages. You will find a variable (I think it's called `$cat_product` if my memory is good) that stores all the products. You can easily check if it is empty or not. Then from here you just have to get the subcategories (there is a method for this in the category class) and then get the product of these categories (there is also a method to get the products of a category). That's just the logic you have to follow and after all the code you need is already in the framework.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple to add new category on main header menu, simply go to modules - Pos Megamenu Customer and add whatever you want.

Done!!